# blocking matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that I have a matrix with non square size such as 30X35 and I want to split into blocks such as 4 blocks  it would be like 15X18 and fill the added cell by zeros could that be done in matlab?

Comment: 15x18 divides into 30x35 nearly 4 times, not 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by copying the matrix (twice) and then setting to 0's the part you want to:

```
m = rand([30 35]);

mLeft = m;
mLeft(1:15, :) = 0;

mRight = m;
mRight(16:end, :) = 0;
```

Or it could be the other way around, first you create a matrix full of 0's and then copy the content you are interested.

```
mLeft = zeros(size(m));
mLeft(16:end, :) = m(16:end, :);
```

A generalisation could be done as:

```
% find the splits, the position where blocks end
splits = round(linspace(1, numRows+1, numBlocks+1));

% and for each block
for s = 1:length(splits)-1
   % create matrix with 0s the size of m
   mAux = zeros(size(m));

   % copy the content only in block you are interested on
   mAux( splits(s):splits(s+1)-1, : ) = m( splits(s):splits(s+1)-1, : )

  % do whatever you want with mAux before it is overwriten on the next iteration
end
```

So with the 30x35 example (numRows = 30), and assuming you want 6 blocks (numBlocks = 6), splits will be:

```
splits =  [1     6    11    16    21    26    31]
```

meaning that the i-th block starts at splits(i) and finsished at row splits(i-1)-1.

Then you create an empty matrix:

```
mAux = zeros(size(m));
```

And copy the content from m from column *splits(i)* to *splits(i+1)-1*:

```
mAux( splits(s):splits(s+1)-1, : ) = m( splits(s):splits(s+1)-1, : )
```

This example ilustrates if you want to have subdivision that span ALL the columns. If you want subsets of rows AND columns you will have to find the splits in both directions and then do 2 nested loops with:

```
for si = 1:legth(splitsI)-1
for sj = 1:legth(splitsj)-1

    mAux = zeros(size(m));
    mAux( splitsI(si):splitsI(si+1)-1, splitsJ(sj):splitsJ(sj+1)-1 ) = ...
    m( splitsI(si):splitsI(si+1)-1, splitsJ(sj):splitsJ(sj+1)-1 );

end
end
```

Comment: that's right but what I want it's to give flexibility to by using to change number of blocks i divide it into two as example but what I want is that the number of blocks dynamic could be 2,4,8,16 like that.

Comment: could you please apply it on example I couldn't get it very well?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `blockproc` ?

Comment: yes, but I couldn't get it because of fun use of handling and want to go throw that matrix using loop or something like that because the block number could be different and the matrix size